# Disable last rows in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and i want to disable the last 5 rows of it how can i do it??below code is not working

```
  protected void gview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
          e.Row.Enabled = e.Row.RowIndex <= 5; //for disabling last 4 rows 
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can also do this by setting rows to only "Read Only"

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Enabled = grid.Rows.Count - e.Row.RowIndex > 4;
    }
}
```

**EDITED:** Assuming your `DataSource` is `DataTable`, you can do something like this:

```
protected void gview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Enabled = dataTable.Rows.Count - e.Row.RowIndex > 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you only disable the rows. What when the order changes and the rows have to be enabled again? `e.Row.Enabled=grid.Rows.Count - e.Row.RowIndex > 4`

Comment: @FSX when i do like what you said my entire gridview is getting disabled any ideas??

Comment: @Newbie, How many Rows are in the Grid? If Total Rows are 4 or below then your whole Grid get disabled as per your requirement in the question.

Comment: There are 10 rows,when i debug grid.Rows.Count is 0 and e.Row.RowIndex is 0

Comment: @Newbie, Ok try your actual DataSource Count instead of grid.Rows.Count. See my edited answer.

Comment: Is there any alternative other than this as i am getting rows.count and row.index as 0

Comment: This is the most easiest solution and it should work fine. RowDataBound event is fired for each Row in the Grid so for the first time you will get RowIndex as 0 thats not the problem but RowsCount should have the correct count in it. Have you tried using the Count of original DataSource like DataTable etc.?

Comment: How come your Source Data have count 0? Why don't you try refilling  the DataTable from DataStore/DB again to get the orignial count back.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you are bnding dataset as datascurce to the gridview, so In RowDataBound bound add following code:

```
public static int count=0;
protected void grdview1_RowDataBound()
 {
   for(int i=0;i< ds.table[0].rows.count;i++) 
    {
      count++;
      if(count>(ds.table[0].rows.count-5))
      {
          e.Row.Enabled = false;
      }  
   }
}
```